# cv2.waitKey() works for 'q' key but does not works for any other keys

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code which is actually a part of one of my projects for Sign Language Recognition.
So I am taking user's hand image in each frame and passing it to model and showing the prediction for the  sign on the screen and I have added a feature where if user presses 's' key then prediction will get appended to string sen and similarily I will show that string sen on screen .

But after running the code, for key 'q' it closes the window without any problems but when I press key 's' nothing happens.

Instead of key 's' , I tried the same with other keys but still nothing happens.

Here's the code :

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from model import predict


def capture():
    sen = ''
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        frame_height = 480
        frame_width = 640
        # a standard frame window of size 640*480
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (frame_width, frame_height))

        # drawing a rectangle in a frame which will capture hand
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (300, 100), (500, 300), (0, 300, 0), 2)

        # rectangle of background of text s
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, 0), (300, 50), (0, 0, 0), -1)
        frame = cv2.putText(frame, 'press q to exit', (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # region of interest i.e rectangle which we drawn earlier
        roi = frame[100:300, 300:500]
        roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi, (5, 5), 0)


        # applying edge detection on roi
        roi_edges = cv2.Canny(roi, 100, 200)
        # cv2.imshow('Edges', roi_edges)


        # to make roid_edges of shape (200,200,1) , specifying color channel which is required for model
        img = np.expand_dims(roi_edges, axis=2)
        cv2.imshow('input for model', img)

        frame = cv2.putText(frame, predict(img), (300, 400), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
            sen += predict(img)
            print(sen)

        # printing whole sentence i.e. sen
        frame = cv2.putText(frame, sen , (300, 500),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('Smile', frame)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


capture()
```

So what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you called the `cv2.waitKey(1)` method multiple times, in this case you should use variable for `cv2.waitKey(1)` because the waiting is that both function calls read the keyboard buffer so the second branch executed only if the software receives the s key right after the evaulation of the first branch (q). Here is the sample code:

```
keys = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if keys == ord('q'):
    break
elif keys == ord('s'):
    print('s is pressed')
```